# Digits of sum of two real numbers to the base $b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let $b>1$ be a fixed integer and $x_n$ , $y_n$ the $b$-digital sequences of positive real numbers $x$, $y$ (to the base $b$),  i.e.,
 $0\leq x_n, y_n<b$, there exists an
integer $N$ such that $x_n=0$ (resp. $y_n=0$), for all $n>N$, and
\begin{array}{c}
  x=\sum_{+\infty}^{-\infty}x_nb^n=\cdots x_{n+1} x_nx_{n-1}\cdots_b \\
  \\
  y=\sum_{+\infty}^{-\infty}y_nb^n=\cdots y_{n+1}y_ny_{n-1}\cdots _b
\end{array}

Now, if $z=x+y$ and $z_n$ is the unique $b$-digital sequence corresponded to $z$,
then

(a) Can one state a formula for evaluating the (two-sided) sequence $z_n$ according to $x_n$ , $y_n$?

(b) Are there any recurrence equations (formulas) for them?

(c) Does somebody know any references for it?

\

Note that the usual algorithm of addition of two real numbers says:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
   \cdots & 0\; \mbox{or}\; 1 &  0\; \mbox{or}\; 1 &  0\; \mbox{or}\; 1 & \cdots \\
 \cdots & x_{n+1} & x_{n} & x_{n-1} & \cdots \\
 \cdots & y_{n+1} & y_{n} & y_{n-1} & \cdots & +\\
 -- & -- & -- & -- & --\\
 \cdots & z_{n+1} & z_{n}& z_{n-1} & \cdots
\end{array}
\end{equation}
hence $z_n=x_n+y_n$ or $z_n=x_n+y_n+1$ mod $b$, but we do not know which one is correct, for a given integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Refers to pre-babylonian carry rule. Start with a large enough $n$, $carry=0$, and proceed backward: if $x_n+y_n+carry<b$ then $z_n=x_n+y_n+carry$ and $carry=0$, else $z_n=x_n+y_n+carry-b$ and $carry=1$.

To formalize the above algorithm, introduce the *carry* as a new sequence, $c_n$, and use the Euclidean division: for each *n*, there is a unique $c_n$ and $z_n$, such that $c_n \cdot b + z_n = x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} + c_{n+1}$.

This defines $z_n$ and $c_n$ unambiguously. However, this set of formula goes backwards (giving you $z_n$ and $c_n$ as a function of of $x_{n+1}$, $y_{n+1}$ and not the reverse). So, to prove unambiguity, you cannot use recurrence, but have to use infinite descent.

They can be used as recurrence algorithms, but with a complication due to the fact that at each step *n* you may have to revise the value of the last digit  of the current approximation, changing it from $z_{n-1}$ to $z_{n-1}+1$  when $x_n+y_n>b$.

In order to do this neatly, look to $z_n$ and $c_n$ not as sequence, but as sequences of sequences $z_k = (z_{k,n})_{n < k}$ and $c_k = (c_{k,n})_{n < k}$, where $z_{k,n}=z_n$ and $z_{k,n}=z_n$ for each $n < k$. Then, you can use recurrence on $k$ and compute a unique $z_{k+1}$, $c_{k+1}$ staring from an arbitrary *end carry* $c_{k,k+1}=0, 1$, which has no impact on lower indexes.

Comment: Thanks, good but, can you formulate your algorithm by using integer and fractional (decimal) part notations to achieve some  recurrence equations  ?. Also, do you know any useful references about it?

Comment: There is NO reccurence equations : at each step $n$ you will have to revise the previous value of $z_{n-1}$ to take into account the carry ofthe next step.

Do you want a computer algorithm (with changing variables) or a more formal mathematical version of the last paragraph.

As far as reference are concerned, they are of the "personal communications" type.